# FontAwesome spinning icon misplaced

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I've tried to mimic the "icon left - text right" boxes from https://fontawesome.com/ by taking over the style sheets. everything works fine until I apply fa-spin to an icon (see the sample). The icon is then misplaced and not centered.

I was just able to fix the issue by creating a clone of .g-im-icon -> .g-im-icon-for-spin and playing around with the top, left and transform styles.

however I was wondering if there would be a generic solution that would work for both spinning and non spinning icons?

```css
.g-im-item {
  border-radius: .25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.125rem 0 rgba(33, 37, 41, .05);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.g-im-icon-c {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 1.95312rem;
  position: relative;
}

.g-im-text-c {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  width: 75%;
}

.g-im-title {
  font-family: fa5-proxima-nova, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.g-im-message {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.g-im-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="g-im-item  k-info-colored">
  <div class="g-im-icon-c">
    <i class="g-im-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="g-im-text-c">
    <h3 class="g-im-title">Title goes here</h3>
    <p class="g-im-message">Test goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="g-im-item  k-info-colored">
  <div class="g-im-icon-c">
    <i class="g-im-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="g-im-text-c">
    <h3 class="g-im-title">Title goes here</h3>
    <p class="g-im-message">Test goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try resetting the origin ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .g-im-icon-c class you could implement flexbox in order to center its items instead of using position absolute, this is happening because the transform property get overwritten by your animation.. that is why your animation isn't centered...

```css
.g-im-item {
  border-radius: .25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.125rem 0 rgba(33, 37, 41, .05);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.g-im-icon-c {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 1.95312rem;
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.g-im-text-c {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  width: 75%;
}

.g-im-title {
  font-family: fa5-proxima-nova, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.g-im-message {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.g-im-icon {
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="g-im-item  k-info-colored">
  <div class="g-im-icon-c">
    <i class="g-im-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="g-im-text-c">
    <h3 class="g-im-title">Title goes here</h3>
    <p class="g-im-message">Test goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="g-im-item  k-info-colored">
  <div class="g-im-icon-c">
    <i class="g-im-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="g-im-text-c">
    <h3 class="g-im-title">Title goes here</h3>
    <p class="g-im-message">Test goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm always impressed about you css guys, how you can solve it that fast and me spending hours trying out stuff. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can try applying negative margin to all spinning icons `.fa-spin`:

```
.fa-spin {
  margin-left: -25%;
  margin-top: -25%;
}
```