# Fontawesome5 spinning stacked and transformed icon misplaced, how to fix?

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome-5

I am trying to make a "saving icon" with a loading effect. For that, I stacked a `fa-save` with a `fa-sync` (https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons).

In order to put the `fa-sync` to the bottom-right side, I used `data-fa-transform` (https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms)

So far, everything worked perfect!

Then, I tried to make the `fa-sync` spins (https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/animating-icons)

But at the end, it does not rotates on its own center. It's rotating around another reference.

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<span class="fa-stack" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <i class="far fa-save fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-sync fa-spin fa-stack-1x" data-fa-transform="right-12 down-12" style="color:darkblue;"></i>
</span>
```

Is there a known bug assigned to that? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong

(I found something similar, but not using stacked icons From this other question *[FontAwesome spinning icon misplaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301797/fontawesome-spinning-icon-misplaced))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to spin the sync icon in the middle of the save (floppy disk) icon... you need to adjust the margin-top for the exact placement, as shown below:

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>

<span class="fa-stack" style="vertical-align: top; ">
    <i class="far fa-save fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-sync fa-spin fa-stack-1x" data-fa-transform="right-12 down-12" style="color:darkblue;margin-top:4px"></i>
</span>


<hr/>
<span class="fa-stack-2x" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <i class="far fa-save fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-sync fa-spin fa-stack-1x" data-fa-transform="right-12 down-12" style="color:darkred; margin-top:22.5px"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realized this snippet is not reproducing exactly the problem that I had, since the property `data-fa-transform="right-12 down-12"` is not affecting the position of the `sync` icon. In any case, your suggestion will help me. Thanks!